Behavior of FLT_ROUNDS vs. fesetround() / fegetround()
Regarding the FLT_ROUNDS macro declared in <float.h>, a footnote in the C standard states:

The rounding mode for floating-point addition is characterized by the implementation-defined value of FLT_ROUNDS:23)
-1 indeterminable
0 toward zero
1 to nearest
2 toward positive infinity
3 toward negative infinity
23) Evaluation of FLT_ROUNDS correctly reflects any execution-time change of rounding mode through the function fesetround in <fenv.h>.

Giving this a try with a little example program:
#include <float.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main()
{
    printf( "Initial FLT_ROUND:  %d\n", FLT_ROUNDS );
    printf( "Initial fegetround: %d\n\n", fegetround() );
    fesetround( FE_TOWARDZERO );
    printf( "Current FLT_ROUND:  %d\n", FLT_ROUNDS );
    printf( "Current fegetround: %d\n", fegetround() );
}

Compiled with:
gcc -std=c11 testme.c -o testme -lm

I get the following output on Linux:
Initial FLT_ROUND:  1
Initial fegetround: 0

Current FLT_ROUND:  1
Current fegetround: 3072

On Cygwin:
Initial FLT_ROUND:  1
Initial fegetround: 0

Current FLT_ROUND:  1
Current fegetround: 3

Given the statement from the standard, I would be expecting:
...
Current FLT_ROUND:  0
...

Is this non-conforming implementation, or did I understand that standard footnote wrongly?
FWIW, trying the same on Android / Termux gives me:
Initial FLT_ROUND:  1
Initial fegetround: 0

Current FLT_ROUND:  0
Current fegetround: 3

This makes me suspect a faulty implementation on both Linux and Cygwin...?

As fesetround() returns a value, it would be good to see that in your test code : "The fesetround function returns zero if and only if the dynamic rounding direction mode was set to the requested rounding direction".

@chux-ReinstateMonica Since I took it a step further and actually read back the changed value with fegetround(), I omitted tue error check for brevity. Kind of like I didn't check the rc of printf(), because I see it's been successful or not. ;-)

This is GCC Bug 30569.
GCC documents this as "implementation-defined behavior":


The rounding behaviors characterized by non-standard values of FLT_ROUNDS (C90, C99 and C11 5.2.4.2.2).
GCC does not use such values.



Termux uses the BSD libc and clang "masquerading" as GCC, which explains the standard-compliant behavior on Android.
